# react-hooks/exhaustive-deps does not work

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to receive missing arguments through dependency warnings while using React Hook.

But it doesn't work.

I've added the code below, and I'd appreciate it if you could tell me what's causing it.

I searched a lot of github issues, but couldn't find the cause or result.

Among the things I looked up, I think it says that it shouldn't be run with react-script, that is, cra, but it's unclear.

`package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js",
  },
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.18.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.25.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^45.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "interpolate-html-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "sass": "^1.54.8",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.6",
    "typescript": "^4.8.2",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.6.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.10.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
```

`.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint', 'prettier', 'react-hooks'],
  extends: ['airbnb', 'airbnb/hooks', 'airbnb-typescript', 'prettier'],
  ignorePatterns: ['**/*.config.js', '**/scripts/**'],
  parserOptions: {
    project: ['./tsconfig.json', './packages/*/tsconfig.json'],
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-uses-react': 'off',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    'react/jsx-filename-extension': [1, { extensions: ['.jsx', '.tsx'] }],
    'react/function-component-definition': [2, { namedComponents: 'arrow-function' }],
    'import/prefer-default-export': 'off',
    'arrow-body-style': ['off'],
    'react/require-default-props': 'off',
    'react/jsx-props-no-spreading': 'off',
    'jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events': 'off',
    'no-restricted-syntax': 'off',
    'react-hooks/rules-of-hooks': 'error',
    'react-hooks/exhaustive-deps': 'warn',
  },
};
```

vscode `settings.json`

```
// eslint & prettier
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "[typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  "prettier.configPath": ".prettierrc",
  "eslint.useESLintClass": true,
  "eslint.options": {
    "useEslintrc": true
  },
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2,

  "cSpell.words": ["classiceditor", "Zustand"],
  "[javascript][typescript][typescriptreact]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": "explicit"
    }
  }
```